# How to use Java in PHP?

Tags: java, php, wordpress, web-deployment

I want to use WordPress for my web development, which is PHP written, including the database connection to MySql. The whole thing is PHP. But I need to use Java to back-end data processing and a number of existing Java open source libraries.

A google search shows that PHP/Java Bridge is a way to go. Is that bridge best way to go? If everything is PHP with WordPress, is still a way to use J2EE technologies, inlcuding JSP, Servelet, etc?

**edit**

Java is needed becaue I need to run machine learning algorithms, libraries for which are only available for Java. Also, PHP may run into efficiency issues when it's used to process large amount of data.

A good example of libraries in Java I am going to use is those processing Big Data, which are mainly Java, like Hadoop.

Comment: Please don't :P

Comment: Try to do the most (everything would be the best case) with PHP. A PHP/Java Bridge can be very dangerous.

Comment: Dangerous? How so @CharlotteDunois?

Comment: I need to use Java libraries that are non-trival and turning them into PHP is not a reality. Java is so popular I guess most Web development should be done in Java/J2EE instead of PHP?

Comment: *I need to use Java libraries that are non-trival and turning them into PHP is not a reality* we need more context here. Isn't a *reality* because you don't want to do it (lazyness, too much time to search/create/whatever it needs to be done) or because there are some odd specific rules given by your boss or contractor that you should use Java for maintenance purposes? Note that we don't know what's happening in your mind to state these oddities.

Comment: PHP is much more popular in web, migrate your java code to PHP

Comment: @Luiggi, first, efficiency may be an issue with PHP; second, machine learning libraries are big and hard to implement by non-experts, and most are Java implementations now.

Comment: It's not impossible. You need to use a common protocol and pass messages between processes. I'd consider setting up some REST service.  You can construct your own protocol using TCP, but I'd advise against it as your setting yourself up for a lot of work and potential bugs.

Comment: @martin Combining Java with PHP would result in a mess. Java is strongly typed while php is not, Java supports multithreading while PHP does not and so on. There are powerful debugging tools and enterprise level frameworks for Java so I would just go with Java and replace wordpress with something else.

Comment: Ok, now you shed some light in the question. You need to use machine-learning libraries that are already written in Java and it's a tedious work to move them to PHP (yes, that's a restriction and a motivation that **should be posted in your question body**). By knowing this, readers could provide better guidance in the solution of your problem (not me, I don't know much about this Java bridge).

Comment: @esdebon, when you say "PHP is much more popular in Web", do you mean the front-end scripting uses PHP much more than Java, or both frond and back end? I am not sure whether many big Internet companies are using Java or PHP for their web applications, such as Google, FB, TWitter products and services.

Comment: It depends on who you ask about popularity @martin. PHP is used by 75% of websites in existence.

Comment: Google, FB (wrote a special PHP engine - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HipHop_for_PHP) and other sites on that scale use PHP.

Comment: Please don't use the comments section for a debate. If you have opinions on PHP vs Java popularity, tweet or blog about it. Getting back to the actual question, @martin can you please edit your question and add all the relevant information to back up why you need to need to mix PHP and Java? Needing machine learning libraries is a decent step in the right direction, but do those libraries need to do something "on their own" based on user data, or are they essential to forming correct page relies; which libraries (have you tried finding PHP equivs); etc.

Comment: @Jay, you mean Google/FB wrote a special PHP engine that can easily communicate with Java/C++ which is running at back-end? As for "%75", may I say most websites don't use Java at all?

Comment: You need to read more about HipHop to understand what it does, it doesn't communicate it compiles. I'm not sure what the stat for Java is on websites @martin, but PHP does the back-end processing on the lion share of websites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very simple answer here is **don't**

PHP is designed to, *at every page request* start up, execute a small series of scripts as a single operation, output the data associated with those scripts and then immediately die after generating the output. It literally does not have time to wait for your Java programs and libraries to do their thing, so don't try to put one in the other, which is why PHP scripts that rely on databases tend to have heavily optimised databases for immediate retrieval, instead of general databases that rely on joins and selects that take a few seconds to form the correct data response. Neither PHP or users browsing websites have time for that.

What you *could* do is wrap your java tools in Java Servlets and have them running on the same server/host that your PHP instance is running from, so that your scripts can access the Servlets as `http://127.0.0.1:7254/...` as it would any other restful API it needs to use while generating your script output, as long as you make damn sure that you're not going to make PHP wait: if it has to send data to your tools, that is a post-and-forget operation, PHP should not be getting any response back other than an immediate "data accepted" or "data rejected" **before** the data is then actually handled by your tools. If you need to post data and then get a result back, you're going to have to use two calls. One to post the data, and then a second call to request the result of that posting.

For instance:

- web page generation chain: WordPress CMS based on PHP -> your database
- web input for processing: WordPress CMS based on PHP -> Java Servlets for machine learning
- data processing chain: Java Servlets for machine learning -> your database

So you build pages *only* based on what's in your data base, you post data to your java Servlets *only* to get them to start doing something and you don't wait for a response, their result will end up in your database and you'll get it for pages once it's in, and your java programs do what they need to do independently of your WordPress setup.

And if you're going to do that, you should probably write that functionality as a WordPress plugin that can talk to your Java Servlets.

And now you have a second project you need to work on: turning your java programs into web servers. Not terribly complex, but definitely something you're going to lose some time on doing right (because you'll need to wrap with servlets, as well as make sure you can have those running without crashing on the same server as your wordpress instance, which is always fun)

Comment: If you want to get really crazy, you could request the data after the page is loaded via AJAX so it doesn't hold up the page rendering.

Comment: indeed, although that's not so much "crazy" as "more realtime", and done by virtually any big single-page app. Gmail being the most obvious example. Data comes in, it's gets stored in immense data sets indexed by databases, and the app simply asks a webserver to check with the databases whether anything has changed since the last check. (this answer isn't actually that "out there", it's simply how you do RESTful APIs between disparate languages if the internet sits somewhere in your chain)

Comment: @Mike, thanks for the great explanation and insights. I need more time to digest this. Is the approach and workflow you are describing is a typical way to deal with this situation, or just a workaround if I have to? I ask this because I am still thinking about whether I need to use WordPress or not? WP is great with many existing functionalities, but if it can't decently work together with Java, I may have to use Java from scratch. Thanks.

Comment: Before answering any of those questions, the first bit of information we'll need is what you want to use that WordPress CMS for. For instance, "having a website that can show scientific data" is nothing like "having a web frontend for doing machine learning".

Comment: Typically, I would want to use machine library to process text data, index them and search with Java Lucene library. On front end, among others the main functionality is a search box to accept user's queries using words.

Comment: So this is two things: 1) letting users search your text index. You could use WordPress for that and use a plugin that can talk to Lucene. 2) making your Java machine learning programs extend the Lucene index based on data runs. These two things are completely independent, unless you want web users to be able to upload data to index. In that case you need an API bridge for PHP to give your java program new data to work with (and nothing more)

Comment: @Mike. Based on information I collected so far, I think WordPress + Java is the combination I can use. Thanks really.

Comment: Good luck. As someone with an Msc in Artificial Intelligence, I've been there before =D